# Плагин NextParticle

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Решил купить плагин [NextParticle](https://nextparticle.nextco.de), но появилось много  вопросов:

1. На какое он время?
2. На скольких сайтов его можно использовать?
3. В чем разница между версией *magic* и *wordpress*?

Answer (score 0):

1. Пожизненная лицензия, включая все обновления

> Lifetime Licence incl. all updates

2. Очевидно на любом количестве сайтов, которые принадлежат Вам.
3. В последней есть интеграция в *Wordpress* (эта версия включает в себя версию *Magic*)

> Plugin for your blog **incl. Magic**